# Bind a List from a Database to a ComboBox Controls collection?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding, combobox

I can apply the first value from the database to the text of the combo box control like this:

```
Entities context = new Entities();

        comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding
            ("Text", context.table1, "column1", true));
```

But I would like to apply the results to a collection or list for the control to bind to and then all results will be returned when the drop down button is clicked. What property do I need to target? "SelectedValue" was not working for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `comboBox1.DataSource` ?

Comment: where would I put that? and is the current code I have necessary?

Comment: I'm not sure, so please just take it for much. But would `comboBox1.DataSource = context.table1;` help you? I'm just guessing from the top of my head.

Comment: Maybe this link can help you more?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984341(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Wow great!! I looked everywhere for that link! Thanks for the quick fix :)